# Reloading module causes different results

Tags: python, import, module, python-module

During testing I added a reload command to my test cases so I could change code in several different places without having to reload everything manually and I noticed the reloads seemed to affect the results of the tests.

Here's what I did:

```
import mymodule
import mymodule.rules as rules

def testcase():
    reload(mymodule)
    reload(rules)

    # The rest of the test case
```

Everything works fine like this, or when both reloads are commented out, but when I comment out the second reload the results of the test are different. Is there something that happens during the reload process that I'm not aware of that necessitates reloading all scripts from a module once the module is reloaded? Is there some other explanation?

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but rules is a separate script inside the package that includes this line:

```
from mymodule import Rule
```

Comment: One of the reasons global state is bad is that it makes unit testing hard.

Answer (score 2):

The information in your question is rather vague, and your terminology rather non-standard.  From

> rules is a separate script inside mymodule.

I infer that `mymodule` is actually a package, and it seems it does not automatically import `rules` upon import.  This implies that after executing

```
import mymodule
```

there will be no `mymodule.rules`, but after executing

```
import mymodule.rules as rules
```

the module `rules` will be imported into the namespace of `mymodule`.  (Side note:  The latter code line is usually written as `from mymodule import rules`.)

After executing the first `reload()` statement, you will get a frsh copy of `mymodule`, which wil not contain `mymodule.rules` – this will only be recreated after the second `reload()` statement.

I had to do a lot of guessing for this answer, so I might have gotten it wrong.  The `reload()` statement has lots of subtleties, as can be seen in its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload), so its better to only use it if you are closely familiar with Python's import machinery.

(Another side note: If `rule.py` resides inside the package `mymodule`, as your setup seems to be, you should use a relative import there.  Instead of

```
from mymodule import Rule
```

you should do

```
from . import Rule
```

I also recommend `from __future__ import absolute_import` for more transparent import rules.)

Comment: If reloading the package means the rules module is not included, shouldn't an exception be raised when the code tries to call a function from rules?

Comment: Also, you are correct, I mean to say package. And the reason I didn't use "from mymodule import rules", as I usually would, is because reload(rules) doesn't work after that sort of import.

Comment: Rule is just a class. rules.py is a bunch of functions that return some commonly used Rule objects. I will look into absolute_import though, thanks.

Comment: @Skunkwaffle: Most likely, you are ending up with two instances of a single module somwehow, but I don't know enough about your setup to be sure.  And yes, you would get an error message if something tried to access `mymodule.rules` while it's not there, but how should I know you didn't?

Comment: I think you might be right about two instances. I'd rather not paste all my code here (there's quite a bit of it), but I'll see if I can find some more details to include to further clarify the structure. Also, I thought explaining that I got results from the test case with both configurations implied there were no errors. My apologies if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing your problem, but I think you may be misusing `reload()`.

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload), `reload()` will

> Reload a previously imported module.

However, if you're running this in a testcase, there won't be any changes to the module between when you import it and when you reload it, right?  In order for there to be changes, I think you would have to be changing those files as the test case runs, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I'm not changing the filed during runs, but I am changing them between runs. Since the test case has already done its own importing, I needed to have a way to update the changes without having to exit the interpreter and start all over. It seems even if I reload the test case, it uses the older version of the module code unless I include the reload statements in the test itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just start up a new interpreter for the testcase?  `$ python testcase.py`?  That way you can be sure that whatever you have in your current interpreter isn't messing with the test case.